# Javascript foreach input in form for Name and Value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, foreach

I am just practicing some javascript and i used to use JQuery a lot! I have had no major experience with raw javascript and i want to learn it just as i did JQuery. I have a simple form and a javascript function to go with it onsubmit and i want to get the name and value of each input in the form with my function but it doesnt seem to work can someone help me out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foreach Practice</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Get() {
            var Form = document.getElementById('Form');
            for(I = 0; I < Form.length; I++) {
                var Value = this.attribute('name').value;
                alert(Value);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="User" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="User" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="javascript:Get();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is probably better suited to code review, but whatever.

```
> function Get() {
```

Variable names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. Also, names should indicate what the function does, a generic "get" function doesn't give much of a hint. A better name might be *getFormValues*.

```
>     var Form = document.getElementById('Form');
```

There is a *document.forms* collection available that can be used as an alternative to calling a method:

```
    var form = document.forms('Form');

>     for(I = 0; I < Form.length; I++) {
```

You should always declare variables in an appropriate scope (noting that ECMAScript only has global, function and eval scope, there is no block scope), especially counters. Also, the form's *length* attribute is the number of controls in the form. Since it's a live collection, getting the length every time when you don't need to is potentially a performance hit, so cache the value:

```
    for (var i = 0, iLen = form.length; i < iLen; i++) {

>         var Value = this.attribute('name').value;
```

The value of *this* is set by how you call a function. If the function is called by a handler, then depending on the browser and method attachment, *this* will reference the element whose listener called the function. In this case, because the function is called by an inline listener, *this* has not been set so will default to the global object.

You can easily pass a reference to the element from the listener if you do:

```
<input ... onclick="getFormValues(this);" ... >
```

Now your function will receive a reference to the element and can conveniently get a reference to the form and iterate over the controls. Finally, it is rare to need to access a form control's attribute values, you nearly always want to access properties. So here's the re-written function:

```
function getFormValues(element) {
    var form = element.form;
    var controls = form.controls;

    for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        alert(controls[i].name + ': ' + controls[i].value);
    }
    // Prevent form submission
    return false;
}
```

Lastly, you are better to call the listener from the form rather than the submit button, since forms can be submitted by means other than clicking a submit button. Oh, and don't call any form control "submit" or use any name that is the same as a form method as it will overwrite the same–named method. You get away with it here due to capitalisation, but that is not much defense.

The related HTML can be (note that the form now doesn't need either a name or id):

```
<form onsubmit="return getFormValues();">
    <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should iterate to form's [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children) and use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute) function to get attribute value.

Try this:

```
function Get() {
    var Form = document.getElementById('Form');         
    var childs = Form.children;         
    for(I = 0; I < childs.length; I++) {                    
        var Value = childs[I].getAttribute('name');                             
        alert(Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the form controls, the *children* collection will get all element children and is not implemented in all browsers in use. There are many other issues with the code that should be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone looking for the answer to this i figured it ou just by using random attempts of rearranging my code but here it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foreach Tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Get() {
            var Form = document.getElementById('Form');
            for(I = 0; I < Form.length; I++) {
                var Name = Form[I].getAttribute('name');
                var Value = Form[I].value;
                alert(Name + ' : ' + Value);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="User" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="Pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Get();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you were to take advantage of the assistance offered and edit your answer accordingly.